# Django framework - makemigrations - no changes detect

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django project, when I am running the makemigrations command, it shows no changes detected. I have also updated my settings.py file. It is still facing the same issue, and I tried writing , but it still isn't working. I'm attaching some screenshots here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkhwB.png)

I'm attaching an another ss i want that output.

Comment: Have you added the app into `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @Ersain yes i've

Comment: @Ersain still its not working

Comment: The application to which you want to migrate is indeed `myadmin` ? Have you checked that there is not already a migrations folder ?

Comment: @Ersain   yess it is myadmin and no there is not any migration folder

Comment: Can you screenshot the structure of your project.

Comment: @McPherson my error is solved it turns out it was a minor mistake in my code for models.py file and thank you so much for help

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: @McPherson  in my models.py file unexpected indent error was there, i solved that and it worked